# Is it possible to ask Powershell to start-process in Windows Terminal instead of a new Window

Tags: powershell, elevated-privileges, windows-terminal

If I run in Windows Terminal PowerShell tab:

```
start-process Powershell -Verb runas
```

It will create a new window. Is there a way to create a tab in Windows Terminal instead?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You must use the Windows Terminal CLI, [`wt.exe`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/terminal/command-line-arguments), as the target executable for [`Start-Process`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/start-process), and pass it the PowerShell CLI ([`powershell.exe`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_powershell_exe) for Windows PowerShell, [`pwsh.exe`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_pwsh) for PowerShell (Core) 7+) as its argument; e.g., with `powershell.exe`:

```
Start-Process -Verb RunAs wt.exe powershell.exe
```

Note that if PowerShell is used as your *default* Windows Terminal profile, you needn't specify an argument for `wt.exe` at all.

If you have a Windows Terminal profile defined for PowerShell (which should be true by default for at least Windows PowerShell), you can request it by *name* or *GUID*, via the `-p` option. A profile *name* must specified in full, with the exact case as defined, (otherwise it is ignored and the default profile is used); e.g.:

```
Start-Process -Verb RunAs wt.exe '-p "Windows PowerShell"'
```

Note:

- The *first* elevated Windows Terminal process invariably opens in a *new window*.
- If at least one such process already exists, you can request that additional elevated processes open as *tabs* in that window with `-w 0` as the first option; e.g.:

  ```
  Start-Process -Verb RunAs wt.exe '-w 0 -p "Windows PowerShell"'
  ```